# What is the intuition behind using the harmonic mean?

Tags: statistics, average, means

Why do we sometimes prefer the harmonic mean to the arithmetic mean?

When is it more relevant to use the former than the latter?

Comment: If you travel from a to b at speed s1, and return from b to a at speed s2, then your average speed is the harmonic mean of s1 and s2, rather than the arithmetic mean. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean#Average_speed

Comment: @coffeemath's example is one of several [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean#Examples).

Comment: @J.G. Yes that's same link I found. I just emphasized the one I often used. It also goes for how fast two workers do a job when working together, given their speeds individually.

Comment: The harmonic mean is most common when the measurement is not linear, but the measure’s inverse is linear. Like in the example mentioned by @coffeemath, traveling a fixed distance at a speed $s_1$ and then at speed $s_2,$ the “average speed” is the harmonic mean, because the linear measure is really the time, and the speeds are $d/t,$ the distance over time.